# C++ idempotence of going through: pointer → reference → pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, language-lawyer

#### My understanding

- In C++, an normal value can be converted to a pointer to itself using `&value`, or to a reference to itself through implicit cast.
- As opposed to Rust, references aren't actual first-class types but merely a binary qualifier that some type declaration sites accept. References can be used transparently as if they were their referee, hiding away the internal pointer<sup>1</sup>. As such, we can use `&refToValue` to obtain a pointer to the referee immediately.

#### Question

**If I convert a pointer, to a reference, back to a pointer, am I guaranteed to get the original pointer back?** This would be the case in Rust, but again, Rust has first-class references defined as "normal" types abstracting over a pointer.

```cpp
// Sample code by @chi
T x;
T* ptr1 = &x;
T& ref = *ptr1;
T* ptr2 = &ref;
assert(ptr1 == ptr2); // Is that always true according to the spec?
```

<sub>1: I know that the C++ standard doesn't require references to be implemented as pointers, but I cannot see how they could be implemented in any other way (not considering context-specific optimizations), especially if the answer to my final question is "yes".</sub>

Comment: Perhaps you should include some pseudocode to clarify. I guess you want something like `T x; T* ptr1 = &x; T& ref = *ptr1; T* ptr2= &ref; assert(ptr1 == ptr2);`. (Also note that in C++ no expression can have a reference type, which might be confusing at first. A reference can still be bound to an lvalue.)

Comment: You might want to tag this question [tag:language-lawyer].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263709/4165552 - this answer seems to be OK?

Comment: @pptaszni that's exactly the answer I'm looking for

Comment: Assuming no evil user-provided `operator&` :-} (as evil `deref` implementation in Rust).

Comment: I find it more helpful to think of references as an **alias**, rather than a "hiding away the internal pointer" (because if there is an internal pointer, it's an implementation detail, and not programmatically exposed; but there doesn't need to be an internal pointer, and the optimizer can very well just (literally) alias the actual object).

Comment: @Eljay I do understand this idea of alias now, I'm just a beginner in C++ and couldn't wrap my head around such a high-level concept in what I merely saw as a C successor. And sure the optimizer _can, in some situations_, remove the reference completely. What I mean is that — in the **general case** — you **have to** represent references as pointers, or you'd be losing information that could be required (like when restoring a real pointer from a ref). That's especially true across ABI/linker boundary.

Comment: *What I mean is that — in the **general case** — you **have to** represent references as pointers...*  That part is incorrect.  It may be true for a specific compiler implementation.  It may be entirely false for another compiler implementation.

Comment: Aside: There is no such thing as implicit cast. A cast is an explicit type conversion, by definition.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit right, I should have said coercion, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I convert a pointer, to a reference, back to a pointer, am I guaranteed to get the original pointer back?

Yes.

---

> references aren't actual first-class types ... binary qualifier that some type declaration sites accept

Indeed, while references are types, they [can't serve as expression types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1).

So e.g. when you do `&*foo`, `*foo` isn't a reference.

Comment: Perfect answer! I appreciate the confirmation of my current understandings about the weirdness of reference types.

Answer (score 7):

> If I convert a pointer, to a reference, back to a pointer, am I guaranteed to get the original pointer back?
>
> ```
> T x;
> T* ptr1 = &x;
> T& ref = *ptr1;
> T* ptr2 = &ref;
> ```

Yes.

---

#### Full explanation on the initialisations

- Per [`[expr.unary.op]/3.2`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3.2), `T* ptr1 = &x` initializes `ptr1` as a pointer to `T` pointing to the designated object (`x`).

> The operand of the unary & operator shall be an lvalue of some type T. The result is a prvalue.
> ...
> (3.2)
> Otherwise, the result has type “pointer to T” and points to the designated object ([intro.memory]) or function ([basic.compound]). If the operand names an explicit object member function ([dcl.fct]), the operand shall be a qualified-id.

- Per [`[expr.unary.op]/1`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1) and [`[dcl.ref]/5`](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#dcl.ref-5.sentence-3), `T& ref = *ptr1` initializes `ref` to refer to a valid object, namely `x` as `*ptr1` performs indirection on `ptr1` and yields an lvalue denoting the object to which `ptr1` points, namely `x`.

> `[expr.unary.op]/1` The unary * operator performs indirection. Its operand shall be a prvalue of type “pointer to T”, where T is an object or function type. The operator yields an lvalue of type T denoting the object or function to which the operand points.
>
> `[dcl.ref]/5` A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.

- Finally, per [`[expr.unary.op]/3.2`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3.2) again, `T* ptr2 = &ref` initializes `ptr2` as a pointer to `T` pointing to the designated object (`x`).

---

#### What about the pointer comparison?

- As per the equality of the two pointers, I raise [`[basic.compound]/3.4`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:represents_the_address):

> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object35 or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively.

and [`[expr.eq]/3.2`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#3.2):

> [refering to the result of ==, as per defined in /1]
> if the pointers are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address, they compare equal.

Meaning, regardless of the actual value of `ptr1` and `ptr2`:

```
ptr1 == ptr2
```

yields `true`.